# Integration problem: Valid method?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**Question**: for any $\mathcal{G}$ which is continuous everywhere such that, $\int_{0}^{1} \mathcal{G}(t)\, dt = 2$ and $\mathcal{G}(1) = 5$ find $f'''(1) - f''(1)$ if 
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^{2}\mathcal{G}(t)\,dt
$$

**Solution:**

I solved this using the following method,

I got $\mathcal{G}(t)=6t-1$ (by **Trial-and-Error**), this satisfies $\int_{0}^{1} \mathcal{G}(t)\, dt = 2$ and $\mathcal{G}(1) = 5$.

\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^{2}(6t-1)\,dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}(x^2-2xt+t^2)(6t-1)\,dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}(x^2-2xt+t^2)(6t-1)\,dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}(6tx^2-12xt^2+6t^3-x^2+2xt-t^2)\,dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{0}^{x}6tx^2\,dt- \int_{0}^{x}12xt^2\,dt+\int_{0}^{x}6t^3\,dt\right.\\ 
&\qquad\quad-\int_{0}^{x}x^2\,dt+\int_{0}^{x}2xt\,dt-\left.\int_{0}^{x}t^2\,dt\right]\\
\end{align*}
and similarly I find $f(x)$.

I agree that **my $\mathcal{G}(t)$** is from Trial and error , there **can be more alternatives** for $\mathcal{G}(t)$.

Does that mean my solution is wrong?

In addition to that, for different $\mathcal{G}(t)$ the value of $f(x)$ will change, am I safe in concluding that there can be many $f(x)$'s?

If there is another better way to solve this, please let me know.

Regards.

Comment: Your solution is only correct under the assumption that the result will be the same, regardless of G. The question suggests that this is the case, so in a certain sense it is correct, but I doubt it is the intention of the question to do it this way.

Comment: @TMM can you suggest an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting
$$f'(x)=\int_0^x(x-t)\mathcal{G}(t)dt,f''(x)=\int_0^x\mathcal{G}(t)dt,f'''(x)=\mathcal{G}(x), $$
one has
$$ f'''(1)-f''(1)=\mathcal{G}(1)-\int_0^1\mathcal{G}(t)dt=5-2=3.$$

Comment: Nice. So, there is no need to get $G(t)$ at all?

Answer (score 3):

> *Can you suggest an alternative solution?*

**Hint**. *Alternatively*, by using [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) twice, one has
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left (\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right )= g\big(x,b(x)\big)\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} b(x) \,-\, g\big(x,a(x)\big)\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} a(x) \,+\, \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x} g(x,t) \,\mathrm{d}t
$$ giving
$$
f'(x) = \int_{0}^{x}(x-t)\mathcal{G}(t)dt
$$ and
$$
f''(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\mathcal{G}(t)dt, \quad f'''(x)=\mathcal{G}(x).
$$ Can you finish it?

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know. Thank you for the help; however, can you please show detailed steps from **first** step to $f'(x)$?

Comment: I get it now. Thank you. :)

Comment: @PragyadityaDas Sure. We have $b(x)=x$, $a(x)=0$ and $g(x,t)=(x-t)^{2}\mathcal{G}(t)$, giving for example $g(x,b(x))=(x-x)^2 \cdot \ldots=0$, $a'(x)=0$... Do you see it?